# Django Model Add Distance Value to each element in model result

Tags: python, django

Using Django and Python 3.x, I'm extracting the elements from a model that are within a given radius from a users location. Due to database restrictions I can't use the built in geo functions in Django. I currently am using the following function:

```
def nearby(self,lat,lng,radius=20,use_miles=True):
    assert isinstance(radius,(float,int))
    assert isinstance(use_miles,bool)
    distance_unit = 3959 if use_miles else 6371
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT deal_ID,("
                    "%d*acos(cos(radians(%f))*cos(radians(%f))*"
                    "cos(radians(lng)-radians(%f))+sin(radians(%f))*" 
                    "sin(radians(lat))))"
                    "AS distance FROM local_deals HAVING distance < %f "
                    "ORDER BY distance ASC;" % (distance_unit,lat,lat,lng,radius))
    ids = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    return LocalDeals.filter(deal_id__in=ids)
```

My question is, how can I add a field "distance", corresponding to the calculated distance to each item returned by the function in the line `return LocalDeals.filter(deal_id__in=ids)`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a reinvention of the wheel. You should use [Dwithin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#dwithin). It does require that GeoDjango is installed but it's fast and bring a lot of different features, not just the ability to do this query easily in just one line.  Your query will be

```
     MyModel.objects.filter(location__diwthin(p,D(m=25)).distance().order_by('distance')
```

here p is some point of interest, D is `django.contrib.gis.measure.D` and m=25 means 25 meters distance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Manager.raw() instead of going to the console? You could try this instead:

```
my_query = "SELECT deal_ID AS id,("
                    "%d*acos(cos(radians(%f))*cos(radians(%f))*"
                    "cos(radians(lng)-radians(%f))+sin(radians(%f))*" 
                    "sin(radians(lat))))"
                    "AS distance FROM local_deals HAVING distance < %f "
                    "ORDER BY distance ASC;" % (distance_unit,lat,lat,lng,radius)
return LocalDeals.objects.raw(my_query)
```

As long as you have id & distance fields in LocalDeals, this would return LocalDeals objects.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries